# CRM 2011 - Enable workflow onload of lead entity using javascript?

Tags: javascript, workflow, dynamics-crm-2011, microsoft-dynamics

I've checked through the forum and cant seem to get what i need to work.

On the lead entity, when a user creates a new lead a Workflow runs just before to change some lead fields.

I found out this is only possible through javascript and onload in the entity settings.

I've created the Workflow and a JavaScript file and set it to run onload. The Javascript i have used is:

```
function callworkfow(workflowId, entityId) {
var request =
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Body>
<Execute xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services"
xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<request i:type="b:ExecuteWorkflowRequest" xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011      /Contracts" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2011/Contracts">
 <a:Parameters xmlns:c="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic">
 <a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
  <c:key>B3D77337-D5FD-E211-BB05-005056AF0003</c:key>
  <c:value i:type="d:guid" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">EntityIdValue</c:value>
      </a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
      <a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
        <c:key>2EF8C158-182B-444A-A9DF-FF2DC5E44514</c:key>
        <c:value i:type="d:guid" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization /">WorkflowIdValue</c:value>
      </a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
    </a:Parameters>
    <a:RequestId i:nil="true" />
    <a:RequestName>ExecuteWorkflow</a:RequestName>
  </request>
    </Execute>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', '/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc/web', true);

xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/xml, text/xml, */*');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml; charset=utf-8');
xhr.setRequestHeader('SOAPAction', 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services/IOrganizationService/Execute');

xhr.onreadystatechange = function () { alert(xhr.status); };
xhr.send(request);
}
```

However this fails to load.

If anyone could help me i would be very grateful. Just need the JavaScript to simply load a Workflow. Oh and with cross platform compatibility.

---

```
function SetLookupValue(fieldName, id, name, entityType) {
    if (fieldName != null) {
        var lookupValue = new Array();
        lookupValue[0] = new Object();
        lookupValue[0].id = id;
        lookupValue[0].name = name;
        lookupValue[0].entityType = entityType;
        Xrm.Page.getAttribute(fieldName).setValue(lookupValue);
    }
}

var ExistingCase = curentUserId = Xrm.Page.context.getUserId();
if (ExistingCase.getValue() != null) {
    var ExistingCaseGUID = ExistingCase.getValue()[0].id;
    var ExistingCaseName = ExistingCase.getValue()[0].name;
    SetLookupValue("new_accountmanager", ExistingCaseGUID, ExistingCaseName, "incident");
}
```

Comment: Do you have any additional script in the file you have added to CRM form? It looks like you are attempting to access to form elements with unsupported way. For example using DOM instead XRM object.

Comment: No none. Its all very standard. I have a requirement to have a workflow change fields as the lead is created. Obviously using workflows in a standard fashion you can only execute after the lead is opened.

Comment: And what fields, entities yours workflow updates?

Comment: At the moment just a custom field to change the field from one option to another. Something simple to see if the script worked.

Comment: You want to change the field on just opened lead form?

Comment: I want the ability to load a workflow or dialog when the lead is opened. In the long run when a new lead is opened i might have a dialogue with questions and a workflow to change some fields.

Comment: I don't clearly understand where the fields you want to change are. Well if you want to change some fields on just opened form - workflow or dialog will not help you to do that: they work only with already created objects, use XRM object and CRM Form SDK in this case.

Comment: On our lead form i want new leads to have 2 fields automatically filled out. If possible i want a workflow to load up when new lead is clicked. I've been told i would need a javascript to do this through onload in the lead properties. Does this not sound possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please check following code, it worked fine for me last time i used it:

```
if (typeof (SDK) == "undefined")
   { SDK = { __namespace: true }; }
       //This will establish a more unique namespace for functions in this library. This will reduce the 
       // potential for functions to be overwritten due to a duplicate name when the library is loaded.
       SDK.Workflow = {
           _getServerUrl: function () {
               ///<summary>
               /// Returns the URL for the SOAP endpoint using the context information available in the form
               /// or HTML Web resource.
               ///</summary>
               var ServicePath = "/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc/web";
               var serverUrl = "";
               if (typeof GetGlobalContext == "function") {
                   var context = GetGlobalContext();
                   serverUrl = context.getServerUrl();
               }
               else {
                   if (typeof Xrm.Page.context == "object") {
                         serverUrl = Xrm.Page.context.getServerUrl();
                   }
                   else
                   { throw new Error("Unable to access the server URL"); }
                   }
                  if (serverUrl.match(/\/$/)) {
                       serverUrl = serverUrl.substring(0, serverUrl.length - 1);
                   } 
                   return serverUrl + ServicePath;
               }, 
           ExecuteRequest: function () {
               var requestMain = ""
               requestMain += "<s:Envelope xmlns:s=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">";
               requestMain += "  <s:Body>";
               requestMain += "    <Execute xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services\" xmlns:i=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">";
               requestMain += "      <request i:type=\"b:ExecuteWorkflowRequest\" xmlns:a=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts\" xmlns:b=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2011/Contracts\">";
               requestMain += "        <a:Parameters xmlns:c=\"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic\">";
               requestMain += "          <a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>";
               requestMain += "            <c:key>EntityId</c:key>";
               requestMain += "            <c:value i:type=\"d:guid\" xmlns:d=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/\">267d4790-e41a-e311-b6a7-3c4a92db481b</c:value>";
               requestMain += "          </a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>";
               requestMain += "          <a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>";
               requestMain += "            <c:key>WorkflowId</c:key>";
               requestMain += "            <c:value i:type=\"d:guid\" xmlns:d=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/\">a6832cc5-1d82-48f5-a940-e41269726204</c:value>";
               requestMain += "          </a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>";
               requestMain += "        </a:Parameters>";
               requestMain += "        <a:RequestId i:nil=\"true\" />";
               requestMain += "        <a:RequestName>ExecuteWorkflow</a:RequestName>";
               requestMain += "      </request>";
               requestMain += "    </Execute>";
               requestMain += "  </s:Body>";
               requestMain += "</s:Envelope>";
               var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
               req.open("POST", SDK.Workflow._getServerUrl(), false)
               req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/xml, text/xml, */*");
               req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
               req.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services/IOrganizationService/Execute");
               req.send(requestMain);
               //work with the response here
               var strResponse = req.responseXML.xml;
               alert(strResponse.toString());
           },
 __namespace: true
};
```

UPDATE:--------------

My previous answer was direct to question. Now providing new answer due to question comments. As it's said in comments workflows can be run only over existing records, but as you said you want to change some field on creation form: record is not saved yet. To do that you must use Xrm object as it is shown below:

```
function OnLoadingForm() {
    var FormType = Xrm.Page.ui.getFormType();
    if (FormType != null) {
        switch (FormType) {
            case 1:
                //  It's a "create" form
                var test = "Mr.";                    
                Xrm.Page.getAttribute("salutation").setValue(test);
                break;
            case 2:
                //  It's a "update" form                              
                break;
            case 3:
                // It's a "readonly" form
                break;
            case 4:
                // It's a "disabled" form
                break;
            case 6:
                // It's a  "bulkedit" form
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

This code works on classic CRM forms (Information forms in customizations). New release may change this. `"salutation"` is name of field from customizations. Notice that this field change is only on form and will be saved to CRM DB after user clicks Save button.

UPDATE 2:-----------
Due to new circumstances new code snippet:

```
function OnLoadingForm() {
    // Get the current FormType
    var FormType = Xrm.Page.ui.getFormType();      
    if (FormType != null) {
        switch (FormType) {
            case 1:
                //  It's a "create" form                

                var curentUserId = Xrm.Page.context.getUserId();
                var serverUrl;
                if (Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl !== undefined) {
                    serverUrl = Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl();
                } else {
                    serverUrl = Xrm.Page.context.getServerUrl();
                }
                var ODataPath = serverUrl + "/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc"; 
                var userRequest = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
                userRequest.open("GET", ODataPath + "/SystemUserSet(guid'" + Xrm.Page.context.getUserId() + "')", false); 
                userRequest.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json"); 
                userRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8"); 
                userRequest.send();
                if (userRequest.status === 200) {
                    var retrievedUser = JSON.parse(userRequest.responseText).d; 
                    var userFullName = retrievedUser.FullName;        
                    SetLookupValue("new_accountmanager", curentUserId, userFullName, "systemuser");
                }
                else {
                    return "error";
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                //  It's a "update" form               
                break;
            case 3:
                // It's a "readonly" form
                break;
            case 4:
                // It's a "disabled" form
                break;
            case 6:
                // It's a  "bulkedit" form
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}

function SetLookupValue(fieldName, id, name, entityType) {
    if (fieldName != null) {
        var lookupValue = new Array();
        lookupValue[0] = new Object();
        lookupValue[0].id = id;
        lookupValue[0].name = name;
        lookupValue[0].entityType = entityType;
        Xrm.Page.getAttribute(fieldName).setValue(lookupValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant thanks i'll give it a try today. Where in the code to i enter my details?

Comment: You should pass only yours record Id and workflow Id into ExecuteRequest function. Replace Guids in requestMain variable.

Comment: this is what i have done but i'm getting an error message when i open the entity.

Comment: Thank you so much this is excellent. This solves my one problem. The other is for the account manager field we have. Basically when a user creates a lead they set them selves as the account manager. I want to make this automated. So i was thinking of using a workflow before hand to set the account manager as lead creator. Any ideas?

Comment: What type Account Manager field is? Look up to User entity?

Comment: See this [post](http://garethtuckercrm.com/2011/03/16/jscript-reference-for-microsoft-dynamics-crm-2011/). It saved few days of my life. P. 14 is what you need.

Comment: sorry to be a pain but for some reason i cant get number 14 to work. I have the 2 lookup fields, in my case existing field to copy is "ownerid" and the one to copy the data to is "new_accountmanager". Added these in to the code and nothing happens.

Comment: Did you debug you code in F12 tool? I think it may be that `ownerid` field is not initialized when you are trying to copy it. Try get current user id with this code and set it to lookup:
`curentUserId = Xrm.Page.context.getUserId();`

Comment: Thought i would put the code up i'm using just to make sure i havent messed it up.

Comment: Thank you so much Update 2 worked perfectly. If you have time i have placed another bit of code. Its the last thing i need to get working. I have created a button and i need to link it to a Dialog. When the button is clicked a Dialog is launched. For some reason it wont work.

Comment: Well you should conciser add this last comment as new question. It is not connected to current question title. See [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: Also do not put your question updates into answers. It confuses a little. Just try to edit your question.

Comment: Sorry, i'll start a fresh question. Thanks for all you help.